# For a ring with idempotent $e$, is $r \mapsto ere$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring with idempotent $e$, then $eRe$ (the corner ring) is also a ring. Then is the map $\varphi(r) := ere$ a homomorphism?

Surely if $e$ is central, then we have $e(rs)e = e^2(rs)e = erese = (ere)(ese)$, but what if $e$ is not neccessarily central?

Comment: The map $\phi(r)=r(1-e)$ is a ring homomorphism. Why do you think that $\phi(r)=ere$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: As stated here http://www.tricki.org/article/Decompose_your_ring_using_idempotents we have $R \cong eRe \times (1-e)Re \times eR(1-e) \times (1-e)R(1-e)$, and I tried to find an explicit isomorphism between $R$ and the direct product of the four rings on the right, and the only choice seems $r \mapsto (ere, re-ere, er - ere, r - er - re + ere)$, but I failed to establish this to be an isomorphisms, as $r \mapsto ere$ is not a homomorphisms...

Comment: It makes sense to look up the Pierce decomposition in some book on ring theory, see for example [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=VtvwJzpWBqUC&pg=PA308&lpg=PA308&dq=ring+idempotent+pierce+decomposition+R%3D+eRe+x+(1-e)Re+x+eR(1-e)+x+(1-e)R(1-e)&source=bl&ots=uEgXt-OTzG&sig=aJ-jIli1ZmuBqfIMM02ukxEbdB4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvvJ_2vYXRAhVEVhoKHeltAgsQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=ring%20idempotent%20pierce%20decomposition%20R%3D%20eRe%20x%20(1-e)Re%20x%20eR(1-e)%20x%20(1-e)R(1-e)&f=false), because they give nice proofs there.

Comment: Seems to be a subtle point here, when they write $R = eRe \oplus \ldots$ they did not mean a decomposition into a direct product of subrings (as your source for example just talks about decomposition into additive subgroups). As shown here in general there is no ring isomorphism between $R$ and $eRe \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)R(1-e)$, right?

Comment: The corner ring $R_e:=eRe$ is indeed a subring of $R$. But you wanted something else, namely a ring homomorphism $R\mapsto R_e$.

Comment: That confuses me a little bit, if it is a direct decomposition into rings, then we must have a isomorphism onto a cartesian product of these components, or not?

Comment: No, $R$ is not a subring of $eRe$, except for the case that $e=1$. And your tricki link just says that as sets $R=R_1\oplus R_2\oplus R_3\oplus R_4$, with subrings $R_1$ and $R_4$. It does not mean that we have ring homomorphisms between them.

Comment: The answers have already brought the obvious theme up: matrix rings over division rings are full of idempotents, and yet the matrix ring is simple, so there are not homomorphisms to many of these corner rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a concrete counterexample, consider $R=M_2(K)$ and  the idempotent $e=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $r=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $s=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \cr c' & d' \end{pmatrix}$,
then we have
$$
\phi(r)\phi(s)=\begin{pmatrix} aa' & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix} aa'+bc' & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\phi(rs).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ring $R$ of $n \times n$ matrices over a field, with $n > 1$. You know that this is a simple ring.

Choose $e = e_{11}$ to be the matrix that has zero everywhere, except for a $1$ in the $(1, 1)$ position.

Then $e R e$ consists of the matrices which are zero everywhere, except possibly in the $(1, 1)$ position.

There is no way $e R e$, a commutative, non-trivial ring, can be isomorphic to a proper quotient of the simple, non-commutative ring $R$.